# Set UIImageView AspectRatio constraint programmatically in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, constraints, aspect-ratio

I have an UIImageView in storyboard which AspectRatio is 1:1, that I want to change to 2:1 programmatically in ViewController in some cases. I create reference of that constraint in ViewController but unable to set the constraint.

Comment: After setting up the constraint, call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change constraint programmatically in swift 3

```
let aspectRatioConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.YourImageObj,attribute: .height,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: self.YourImageObj,attribute: .width,multiplier: (2.0 / 1.0),constant: 0)
self.YourImageObj.addConstraint(aspectRatioConstraint)
```

Answer (score 18):

As it's stated in [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html), there're three ways to set constraints programmatically:

- You can use layout anchors
- You can use the NSLayoutConstraint class
- You can use the Visual Format Language

The most convenient and fluent way to set constraints is using Layout Anchors.

It's just **one line** of code to change aspect ratio for your ImageView

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0/2.0).isActive = true
```

[image: Result View]

To avoid **"[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."** you should add reference to your ImageView's height constraint then deactivate it:

```
heightConstraint.isActive = false
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the multiplier of the constraint to 0.5 or 2 depending on your constraint condition, It'll become 2:1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am not clear about it. I tried to set constraints like this, 'cons_coverImageRatio.constant.multiply(by: 0.5)'. But its not working. Would you show me how to set that constraint

Comment: simple use like `self.imageAspectConstraint.multiplier = 0.5`, and then call `self.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: multiplier is a get property so can't assign it